# Calculate form progress with Angular js

Tags: angularjs

I have a simple with two fields. Each field associated with two radio buttons.
I want to calculate the form progress..Markup of the form look like this

```
<fieldset>
    <div>
        <div class="btn-group">
            <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="radio" />
            </label>
            <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="radio" />
            </label>
        </div>
        <label for="FH1" class="radio-inline control-label">1st Option</label>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div>
        <div class="btn-group">
            <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="radio" />
            </label>
            <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="radio" />
            </label>
        </div>
        <label for="FH1" class="radio-inline control-label">2nd Option</label>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

I have a directive define for formprogress

```
<formprogress progress={{progressValue}} />
```

Assume that "progressValue" is a scope variable, now I want to update this value somehow, to show the form progress.How it would possible?

Comment: And what exactly do you mean by form progress?

Comment: Like, how many fields in the form form have been filled.. I want to show the form progress in percent...Like If I just select one radio button in my case, the form progress will be 100%

Comment: Well, you need the total number of fields in a variable, and then, upon each input change, calculate the `$scope.progressValue` as filled in fields divided by total fields.